# Is the product of a null subset and a subset a null subset?

Tags: lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to prove that **if A is a null subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$ and B is a subset of $\mathbb{R^m}$, then A x B is a null subset of $\mathbb{R^{n + m}}$**. But I'm stuck with this prof, does anyone know how to prove it?

Comment: By *null subset* you mean a set of measure zero, and not the empty set, correct?

Comment: Yes, as you said, A is a subset of measure zero and I think that A x B should be a subset of measure zero, but I can't prove it.

Comment: Do you mean $\Bbb{R}^{n+m}$ instead of $\Bbb{R}^{n \times m}$? Also, what is your definition of a null subset? Depending on that definition, you might be able to prove it directly, only using that definition.

Comment: yes, that is a mistake, I mean $\mathbb{R^{n + m}}$, thanks for pointing it. And my definition for a null set is:

Let A be a subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$, A is null if given $\epsilon > 0$ there is a succession of rectangles fited (I don't know if the translation of fited is correct, sorry) and open n-dimensional $ \{ I^{(j)} \} _{j=1}^\infinity $ such that:

1) A is in the union of the $I^{(j)}$
2) summatory of the measure of the $I^{(j)}$ < $\epsilon$

Comment: As a quick hint, it may be easier to first consider the case when $A$ is countable (or even finite).

Comment: Thanks, I will try that approach.